# AngularJS - Set the true or false or select one option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set whatever I choose i want to save it to viewmodel but I can't figure out how to set option that I selected to ng-model. If nothing is selected value will be select one. Available options are YES (true) / NO (false). Thanks guys

```html
<select automationid="APR" name="cost"
                            class="ddl"
                            ng-model="tempDefaultCost.cost"
                            ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in costFlyoutCtrl.trueFalseLookup">
                        <option value="">Select One</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, You can add an extra option to select box which is `disabled` and `selected`:

with `ng-repeat`:

```
<select automationid="APR" name="cost" class="ddl" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedItem">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Select one</option>
       <option ng-repeat="x in $ctrl.items">{{x.label}}</option>
</select>
```

and also with `ng-options`:

```
<select automationid="APR" name="cost"
                            class="ddl"
                            ng-model="$ctrl.selectedItem"
                            ng-options="x.label for x in $ctrl.items">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select one</option>
</select>
```

And in your controller:

```
this.items = [{value: true, label: 'TRUE'}, {value: false, label: 'FALSE'}];
this.selectedItem;
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-2vn1fs?file=home/home.html)